# Elasticsearch service failed to start on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, elasticsearch

I can't start the Elasticsearch service on my [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa) installation:

```
 #systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-10-17 21:30:19 UTC; 27min ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 2133147 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet>
   Main PID: 2133147 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 17 21:30:18 stavilelk01 systemd-entrypoint[2133147]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(>
Oct 17 21:30:18 stavilelk01 systemd-entrypoint[2133147]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.exec>
Oct 17 21:30:18 stavilelk01 systemd-entrypoint[2133147]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHand>
Oct 17 21:30:18 stavilelk01 systemd-entrypoint[2133147]:         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79)
Oct 17 21:30:18 stavilelk01 systemd-entrypoint[2133147]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Ela>
Oct 17 21:30:18 stavilelk01 systemd-entrypoint[2133147]:         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Ela>
Oct 17 21:30:18 stavilelk01 systemd-entrypoint[2133147]: For complete error details, refer to the log at /home/admin_e>
Oct 17 21:30:19 stavilelk01 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 17 21:30:19 stavilelk01 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 17 21:30:19 stavilelk01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

Here are the logs:

```
/var/log/elasticsearch# journalctl -xe
-- Automatic restarting of the unit logstash.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 systemd[1]: Stopped logstash.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit logstash.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit logstash.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 5920063 and the job result is done.
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 systemd[1]: Started logstash.
-- Subject: A start job for unit logstash.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit logstash.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 5920063.
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 logstash[2143095]: Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 logstash[2143095]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was depreca>
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sda: add missing path
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sdb: add missing path
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sdb: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sdb: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
Oct 17 21:58:36 stavilelk01 multipathd[828]: sdb: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu as a VMware virtual machine? Or is this a bare metal installation? 

Comment: my ubuntu is running on VM.

Answer (score 3):

VMWare does not provide information needed by `udev` to generate `/dev/disk/by-id` entries. A number of the VMware products have this habit. The solution is to edit the `.vmx` file for your virtual machine, adding this:

```
disk.EnableUUID = "TRUE"
```

After a reboot, the disks will be properly visible and `multipathd` won’t complain anymore. This may resolve your elastic search issue.

Comment: hello, i tried the solution that you propose but it dosen't work: ~# service elasticsearch start
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.